# Force native windows frame and titlebar

Tags: windows, desktop-customization, title-bar

Several programs have their own frame, titlebar and minimize/maximize/close buttons, such as Chrome with certain skins, such as this one which forces a Windows 7 like buttons.

[image: Chrome]

Or in Discord:

[image: Discord]

I am aware of certain options within Chrome, I want an option that works all across the Windows 10 shell, because I use programs like RBTray, which are not compatible with custom frames, and because I don't like the clash between custom frames and the native Win10 frames.

Comment: It's not possible to globally override program specific skins if they don't have an option to do so.

Comment: @DavidPostill But couldn't one make a launcher that would surround the program with the native windows frame, so the program would have two frames, but at least one of them would be native?

Comment: Not easily. In any case that would be even more ugly ...

Comment: for me it would enough to have titlebar in chrome, but current version does not have any flag containing "title", so how can I turn it on?